# * { Box-sizing: border-box; } : To border-box or not to border-box all elements?

Tags: css, margin, padding, border-box

I will start developing a new website, and I'm getting ready to deal with the different methods browsers use to calculate width and height of elements ([box model stuff](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html)). Somehow, it came to my mind: what if I just apply `box-sizing` to all elements in the website?

I'm one of those who believe that `box-sizing: border-box;` is one of the best commands there is in CSS, with all its limitations. However, those same limitations are the ones who make me wonder if I should apply `box-sizing` to all elements:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Of course my website should be compatible with as much browsers as possible, and `box-sizing` creates a few questions when we think about IE7-. However, sometimes the schedule is so tight that it would be great to gain a few extra minutes by not worrying about this specific issue.

Anyway, do you think that applying `box-sizing:border-box;` to all elements is a good policy or should I keep doing so only to the elements that actually need it?

Comment: I'm also one for border-box. You might want to read this as well http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is a great idea. In fact I will start doing the same on my websites.

Here Paul talks about using it in that same fashion

http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

> We've been using *{box-sizing: border-box;} in one of my projects
>   (deployed in production, averaging over 1mln visits a month) at work
>   for about a year now, and it seems to be holding up just fine. The
>   project has been tested in IE8 & 9 and the latests Firefox and Chrome
>   versions and we've had no problems. All jQuery (+UI) offset
>   calculations and animations run fine, even in any element we've
>   displayed as inline-block. As of late we've started testing the
>   project on mobile devices (iPhone, iPad and Android) and we've had no
>   issues regarding box-sizing with any of them yet, so it seems to work
>   just fine.

I found this to help take care of the issues in IE7

https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill