# *{ box-sizing: border-box }

Tags: css, fancybox, padding

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is this a good idea? Any drawbacks?

I find this very useful when I want an element to have 100% and some inner padding. Because I don't have to add another element inside for the padding :/

Comment: Related link [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: If you are using fancybox v1.3.4 then check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19921314/1055987

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To border-box or not to border-box all elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722841/to-border-box-or-not-to-border-box-all-elements)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have started to use this almost always.

**The Pros**,

You do not need to calculate out the CSS box-model anymore.

You can easily add large `padding` to an object without have to re-fix your height/width

Faster coding of your css (look up SASS if you have not)

**The cons**,

IE7 and below have no support, who cares right? Some sadly do.

IE8 and up have only partial support.

**This is how I go about this if I don't want everything to have it**,

```
div, li, p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I add the elements that *I know* will utilize this property and to prevent every object from having that property.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest drawback is that it doesn't work in a lot of browsers, most specifically < IE8. Check it out the usage [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).

When I use this, I usually make sure I have all of the following in my stylesheet

```
.my-element {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```