# Box sizing suddenly stopped working

Tags: html, css, styles

I´m using the box-sizing: border-box; element to make my boxes on my website behave the same on multiply browsers. It has worked perfectly great since I started create the website but today the box-sizing element suddenly stopped working. I´ve no clue on what´s can be the problem. Help would be much appreciated!

Here´s a link to my website: http://amazive.com
As you can see, all the boxes have put the padding "outside" instead of "inside" the boxes.

This is my reset code:

```
* {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thanks,
Fredrik

Comment: What browser are you testing with just for clarification?

Comment: Including the link to the website will not get you a good answer. Try and replicate the problem with the minimum code possible and post that here.

Comment: Issue is present on Aurora (Firefox 28)

Comment: Im testing in chrome, ff and ie.

Comment: stackErr I don´t know which code which would be in interest for this problem except for the code presented.

Comment: @user3250205 Is the below answer what you were looking for?  If not please let me know and I will modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading your site I see the following error in the console:

```
Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. main.css:1
```

If you look at the first line of your `main.css` file you'll see it is:

```
</*****************************************************
```

Remove the leading angle bracket so it looks like:

```
/*****************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you want `box-sizing; border-box;` to be on all of your elements?
To do it use this code

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Here is a codepen sample:
http://codepen.io/camdixon/pen/DgrGC

I got the answer from here:
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

A more detailed answer and IE tricks found here: 
[* { Box-sizing: border-box; } : To border-box or not to border-box all elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722841/to-border-box-or-not-to-border-box-all-elements)

Comment: Found that too, but this isn´t working either. Thanks annyway!