# Image and button with same width percentage has different width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this in my HTML file, you can see that the image tag and the button tag has the same width (40%) in the style attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <img src="Assets/Blimp VB.png" alt="Preview of my second attempt to make a game" width="40%" style="
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;">
                
        <button type="button" style="
          height: 100px;
          width: 40%;
          border: 2px solid black;
          border-top: none;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;"
        >2nd attempt to make a game</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And when I run the  file, I the div looked like this:

[image: A picture of the dive, with the slightly wider bit circled]

Why is the image still wider than the tag? I'm assuming that the width doesn't take account of the border, but then how do I fix this?

Also, I'm not promoting Blimp, I'm using that as a placeholder for the preview of the project.

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `<img>` tag. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722841/box-sizing-border-box-to-border-box-or-not-to-border-box-all-elements

Comment: I wished you answered instead of commenting, how do I close this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this way??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex; 
                flex-direction: column;
                border:2px solid black;
                border-radius:20px;
                overflow:overlay;
                max-width:400px;">
        <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=49ed3252c0b2ffb49cf8b508892e452d" alt="Preview of my second attempt to make a game" width="100%" >
                
        <button type="button" 
           style="height:100px;
                  width:100%;
                  outline:0px solid;">2nd attempt to make a game</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what you've done to the code to achieve this? Since I can't clearly see what is going on when you smashed all of the style rules in one line

Comment: @Falling10fruit you have to put your border on the div give it a max-width that you want then inside you have to overlay all the overflow on it. make all inside of the div 100% because the parent div max width is 400px so that will follow it. hope this explains

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width:400px;">
        <img src="Assets/Blimp VB.png" alt="Preview of my second attempt to make a game" width="100%" style="
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;">
                
        <button type="button" style="
          height: 100px;
          width: 100%;
          border: 2px solid black;
          border-top: none;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;"
        >2nd attempt to make a game</button>
</div>
```

try this code :)

Comment: No it doesn't work, also @kmoser already answered.

Comment: how about... set the percent in px?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that, and just like I said kmoser already fixed it by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `<img>` tag

Comment: When you put up an answer please don’t just show code but give an explanation of what it is doing and how it will overcome the problem.